# error: SDL.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, sdl

When i try to include SDL, it prints an error:

```
error: SDL.h: No such file or directory
```

My system is Mac OSX Lion and i´ve installed SDL.

I use this:

```
#include "SDL.h"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the include directory of the `SDL.h` header to `gcc` with the option `-I`.

For example:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/SDL -c test.c
```

Comment: And it's better practice to use `#include <...>` if the header isn't part of your source.

Comment: @HackWeb you have to replace the `/usr/include/SDL` directory in the example with the directory in YOUR system where `SDL.h` is installed. The `find` command is your friend.

Comment: I know this is controversial, but I would instead use `#include <SDL/SDL.h>` and assume the `SDL` include directory is located somewhere in the default include path. If it's not, it would be reasonable to expect the person building the project to add the necessary `-I` options manually or via a `configure` option.